# How can I remove a class inside my table with "$(this)"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove the class **fail** from the **first** table row when I click inside `img` with **id="rollback1"** without removing the class fail from the table row two.

```
<table>
  <tr>        
   <td class="fail">      
   </td>

   <td>
     <img id="rollback1"></img>
   </td>        
  </tr>

  <tr>        
   <td class="fail">      
   </td>

   <td>
     <img id="rollback2"></img>
   </td>        
  </tr>
</table>
```

I tried this:

```
$("#rollback1").on('click',function(){
 $(this).find('.fail').removeClass();
});
```

And also this:

```
$("#rollback1").on('click',function(){
 $(this).prev().removeClass();
});   

$("#rollback1").on('click',function(){
 $(this).closest('.fail').removeClass();
});
```

Still, can't figure out, how i can remove a class from just one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can target the element with `parent()` and `prev()` like the following way:

```js
$("#rollback1").on('click',function(){
  $(this).parent().prev('.fail').removeClass('fail');
  // if you have `td` in between use siblings()
  //$(this).parent().siblings('.fail').removeClass('fail');
});
```

```css
.fail{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>        
   <td class="fail">11      
   </td>
   <td>
     <img id="rollback1" src="" alt="1"/>
   </td>        
  </tr>

  <tr>        
   <td class="fail"> 22     
   </td>

   <td>
     <img id="rollback2" src="" alt="2"/>
   </td>        
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Unless you add another `<td />` between the two existing ones… 

Comment: @Kenai, you are most welcome....If you have another `td` in between then instead of using `prev()` use `siblings()` like `$(this).parent().siblings('.fail').removeClass('fail');`........thanks.

Comment: @Mamun Thats nice! can i use siblings if the class is inside TR?

Comment: @Kenai, do you mean the class in `tr` element?

Comment: @Kenai, no, in that case the hierarchy will change. Right now the image is inside of a `td`, using `parent()` you are targeting that `td`. Then using `siblings()` you can target the element with the class at the same level of that parent `td`.

Comment: @Kenai, I really love to.....but I have to leave my desk now.....may be some other time....hope you understand......thanks.

Comment: I managed to figure out. Thank you for your attention, i'm sorry for anything.
I did this: $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('fail');

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like:

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('td.fail').removeClass('fail');
```

You could use `id` and start with selector `^=` like:

```
$("[id^=rollback]").on('click', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.fail').removeClass('fail');
});
```

```js
$("[id^=rollback]").on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').find('.fail').removeClass('fail');
});
```

```css
.fail {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td class="fail">TD 1</td>

    <td>
      <img id="rollback1" alt="IMAGE 1" />
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td class="fail">TD 1</td>

    <td>
      <img id="rollback2" alt="IMAGE 2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**My suggestions:** I suggest one of the following solutions :

1. Target by `img` tag like :

   ```
   $("table img").on('click', function() {
      //Your code
   });
   ```
2. Use common class instead like :

   ```
   $(".rollback").on('click', function() {
      //Your code
   });
   ```

   Then your HTML code must be like :

   ```
   <img class="rollback" id="rollback1" alt="IMAGE 2" />
   <img class="rollback" id="rollback2" alt="IMAGE 2" />
   ```

Comment: My advice, you shouldn't use `prev()` since it will not work properly if you made any change in positions... in addition, the `closest` method is more efficient than `parent`

Comment: Thank you, Zakaria.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#rollback1").on('click',function(){
 $(this).parent().find('.fail').removeClass();
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

If `#rollback2` should do the same on the second row, you could do something more generic:

```
$('img[id^="rollback"]').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('.fail').removeClass('fail');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The **closest() method** returns the first ancestor of the selected element.

An ancestor is a parent, grandparent, great-grandparent, and so on.

And the **find() method** returns descendant elements of the selected element.

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.fail').removeClass('fail');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#rollback1").on('click', function() {
 $(this).closest('table').find('tr:nth-child(1)').removeClass('fail');
});
```